# How to change left border width in Zen Mode PhpStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I started using the PhpStorm IDE.

I found the perfect mode for coding called Zen Mode.
But I have one point to make about this. Its left border is so wide. How can I change this?

[image: PrtSc of Zen Mode.]

Comment: In Zen / Distraction Free mode the code is kind of centred (has a big gap on the left). It is by design. You may want to use just "full screen" mode instead. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.1/ide-viewing-modes.html. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148002 and check the comments and linked tickets there.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Didn't find an answer, and now I'm using full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

In Zen / Distraction Free mode the code is kind of centred (hence that big gap on the left: it gets bigger on a wider screen). It is by design. You may want to use **Full Screen mode** instead. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.1/ide-viewing-modes.html

You may also want to check these links for some tips on how to customize your IDE:

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/04/ui-secrets-customize-the-appearance-of-intellij-idea/
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/02/find-your-visual-zen/
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.1/tool-windows.html

---

Regarding the editor gutter width in general: see [IDEA-148002](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148002) and check the comments and linked tickets there.